# При загрузке apk в Google Play появляется ошибка

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play

В чем может быть проблема? При тестировании на устройствах, приложение работает исправно, а как сгенерировал apk, так сразу появилась ошибка

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Релизный апк необходимо подписывать отдельным релизным сертификатом.
При тестировании использовались debug-сборки, которые подписываются одинаковым сертификатом для всех приложений.

Подписанный апк можно получить используя "Generate signed APK" или через настройки signing configs в build.gradle. НЕ рекомендую хранить открытым пароль в build.gradle

Comment: Попробуйте более подробно расписать, иначе ТС вас не поймет. Даже я не понимаю (имея ввиду, что есть понятие debug сертификата и release сертификата).

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка была довольно глупой

Answer (score 1):

Решение. Во время подписи, помимо **Full APK Signature**, нужно отметить еще и **Jar Signature**. Раньше в Android Studio такого не было
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]